# No Destroy when creating Post Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run:

`bin/rails generate scaffold Post title:string`

When navigating to 'http://localhost:3000/posts', I see a list of posts that I have created.

I see options for 'Show', 'Edit', 'Destroy'

When clicking 'Destroy' next to the Post, I am expecting to see an alert box asking me to confirm the 'Destroy' option.

After clicking 'Ok' I expect to see the Post removed from the list, and to see a 'Post was successfully destroyed.' message.

However, when I click the 'Destroy' option next to the Post, I get navigated to 'http://localhost:3000/posts/1'

From this page, I have the 'Edit' and 'Back' options with the original list of Posts in tact.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by no "functionality when on that page"? What exactly is it that you expected to happen and what was the actual result? Please reply by editing your question to clarify it. Not commenting.

Comment: @max Looks like UJS is not functioning. Instead for `DELETE` it sends `GET` request

Comment: @AmitPatel yeah that was my initial suspicion as well. @trailrunner89 - this is a really common issue, but the solution is often less straight forward as there are many reasons why the Rails UJS javascript hander  that turns clicking a link into a  DELETE request can fail. Start by checking the console in the browser for errors. See [`data-method`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#data-method) for an overview of how it works.

Comment: @max @AmitPatel - thanks for this guys, really big help. I just looked into the controller with some help, it seems to be missing `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`. This doesn't seem to have fixed the problem though.

Comment: @max @AmitPatel Getting these two console errors - currently looking into how to fix, `GET http://localhost:3000/javascripts/default.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
`GET http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/default.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: The issue is most likely that you're not running the webpacker-dev server. With Rails 6 you need to run a separate assets server by running `bin/webpacker-dev`. See  https://prathamesh.tech/2019/08/26/understanding-webpacker-in-rails-6/

Comment: `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` is actually set by a callback. If you check the top if the file it should contain something along the lines of `before_action :set_post ...` and there is a `set_post` method at the bottom which sets the instance variable. Very common idiom in rails for code resuse.

Comment: @max - thanks for this could the problem be that I'm running Rails `5.0.7.2`?